# Cannot access event.layer in Leaflet.Geoman

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I am using Leaflet-Geoman to draw on map. Drawing and editing works perfectly.

When the user has finished drawing I need to access the layer with the drawing for further processing. See an example here:

```
map.on('pm:drawend', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.layer);
});
```

This returns "TypeError: event.layer is undefined". How can I get the layer of the event?

Answer (score 2):

The `pm:drawend` event has no layer object.

You have to use `pm:create`:

```
map.on('pm:create', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.layer);
});
```